# INDEX MATCH array

Tags: indexing, google-sheets

If A2 is not blank AND matches Sheet2!A2 AND Sheet2!AB2 is not blank, then I want to return `1`. Otherwise leave blank.

Am I close?

```
=IF(A2<>"",IF(AND(INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!AB:AB,0))),1,""),"")
```

Comment: For which? I spose it could for any. I could replace my blank cells with zeros or I could deal with zero as my result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all sure why you are using MATCH (maybe I "just don't get it") so have a formula that is my understaning of your requirement expressed in a way that may make it easy for you to see where I am going wrong. Since multiplying Booleans the results are either `1` or `0`, hence my checking `0` might be acceptable. As you mention, if blank is obligatory it is easy enough to adjust for that.

```
=(A2<>"")*(Sheet2!AB2<>"")*(A2=Sheet2!AB2)
```

Comment: Because I want to match A2 to the same value in Sheet2!A2 and return a value based on the contents of a different cell in that row. Am I approaching this wrong?